# Filter the data inside a stored procedure using Table-Value parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, query-optimization, table-valued-parameters, parameter-sniffing

I have a stored procedure which receives multiple table-type parameters and I want to filter the data using those parameters. The problem with that is those parameters can contain no rows and in that case a join will not work properly.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IntListTableType] AS TABLE ([Id] INT NULL);
```

version 1 - using left joins and where conditions

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FilterUsers]    
    @UserRoles IntListTableType READONLY
       ,@UserTypes IntListTableType READONLY
AS 
    BEGIN
          SELECT UserId, Name 
          FROM Users u
          LEFT JOIN @UserRoles ur on u.RoleId = ur.Id
          LEFT JOIN @UserTypes ut on u.UserTypeId = ut.Id
          WHERE 
             (NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @UserRoles) OR ur.Id IS NOT NULL)
             AND 
             (NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @UserTypes) OR ut.Id IS NOT NULL)
       END
```

version 2 - without joins

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FilterUsers]    
    @UserRoles IntListTableType READONLY
       ,@UserTypes IntListTableType READONLY
AS 
    BEGIN
          SELECT UserId, Name 
          FROM Users u
          WHERE 
             (NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @UserRoles) OR EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @UserRoles ur where u.RoleId = ur.Id))
             AND 
             (NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @UserTypes) OR EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM @UserTypes ut where u.UserTypeId = ut.Id))
       END
```

version 3 - dynamic SQL ???

I'm trying to find a solution from the performance perspective, and also to avoid parameter sniffing.

Comment: Version 2 is likely what you want, however, have you considered adding `RECOMPILE` to your `OPTION` clause in the query?

Comment: Side note, you don't need a `TOP (1)` in an `EXISTS` clause; the data engine automatically "short circuits" as soon as it finds a row.

Comment: Also indexing your column `ID` in your `TYPE` `dbo.IntListTableType` will be a good idea.

Comment: the stored procedure has the OPTION RECOMPILE but that is creating a new execution plan each time affecting the performance

Comment: So you are saying that the cost of rebuilding the plan is *more expensive* that the instance using a plan that isn't relevant? For such a simple query, I very much doubt this.

Comment: that stored procedure is just a simplified version of the stored procedure. the stored procedure has about 15 parameters of that type and is querying from multiple tables (a view in fact)

Comment: Perhaps that's the *real* problem then, and as we don't have a realistic representation of your procedure, we can't make realistic suggestions.

Comment: I don't know/ I didn't find any way of splitting that stored procedure, since most of the where clauses are on a single table.  <br/>

(NOT EXISTS(SELECT FROM @@Var1) OR EXISTS(SELECT FROM @@Var1 v1 where table.Col1 = v1.Id)) AND  <br/>
...  <br/>
(NOT EXISTS(SELECT FROM @@VarN) OR EXISTS(SELECT FROM @@VarN vN where table.ColN = vN.Id))  <br/>